# Which is one is better map.put(key,map.getOrDefault(key,0)+1) or map.compute(key,(key,value)->value+1))

Tags: java, hashmap

In the code below , I have added some keys with their values in map. And then I am trying to add value to key "tie" in map. If it is not present in map, then I am setting its value as 1 otherwise and I am adding 1 to its already existing value.

```java
        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("shoes",100);
        map.put("shirt", 40);
        map.put("pants", 200);
                
        int value;
        //First approach
        value = map.compute("tie",(k,v)->{
            //k is of type String and v is of type Integer
            v = v == null ? 0 : v;
            return v+1;
        });
        //Second approach
        //map.put("tie",map.getOrDefault("tie",0)+1));
```

There are two ways to achieve that

1. By using compute() method of map
2. By using getOrDefault() insiste put() method

Can someone please help me which method have better performance and which one is preferred.

Comment: I think I would use `merge`: `map.merge("tie", 1, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue + newValue);`

Comment: `which method have better performance` - none of these is likely to cause a bottleneck in your application, hence you shouldn't care about it. From the perspective of readability, `Map.merge()` would be preferred in this case.

Comment: @Alexander Ivanchenko performance questions should be considered on their own merits and not automatically discounted because it might not be the actual main issue in the application (which, by the way, we know nothing about). Who is to say that this operation won't be called trillions of times?

Comment: @rghome `operation won't be called trillions of times` - I see no mention of this. And if performance is really concerned, if it is a critical part of the application, there has to be performance tests. Only relevant requirements should be taken into consideration, otherwise you'll end up with *Premature Optimization*.

Answer (score 3):

The merge method is simpler to use.

If you are using a concurrent implementation of Map, it may also be safer, because it can implement proper synchronization.

```
Map<String,Integer> = ... ;
map.merge("key", 1, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach uses counter and `computeIfAbsent(k,v)` as follows:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
HashMap<String,AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String item : List.of("shoes", "shoes", "shirt", "pants", "tie")) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(item, s -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
}
System.out.println("map="+map);

// Prints something like: map={tie=1, shirt=1, pants=1, shoes=2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `HashMap` can't store `int` primitives anyway and it will have to wrap them in an `Integer` via autoboxing. This is never going to be very efficient if you are updating the value of the integer a lot.

Instead, you might consider using a `MutableInt` from Apache commons lang instead of `Integer`. Then you can just get the value and increment it directly. You would need to be careful when handing out references to the value you get as anyone will be able to update the value in the map.

You could also consider using a collections library that implements object-to-int maps directly. For example, fastutils (but there are others): https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2IntOpenHashMap.html.